# Time passes by and I'm freezing

Tags: riddle

I am like grass and mountains
so many things before the end
an angled shape on the rear
no dangerous knife within my gear
anyone who shines is worth a lot
and it unfortunately never stops.

What am I?

Comment: The title describes me perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you

> Lines from the song All Star, by Smash Mouth?

---

Time passes by and I'm freezing

> "It's a cool place and they say it gets colder"

I am like grass and mountains

> ??

so many things before the end

> "So much to do, so much to see" (the song then alludes to the end of the world)

an angled shape on the rear

> "She was looking kind of dumb with her finger and her thumb / In the shape of an "L" on her forehead" (but why "rear"?)

no dangerous knife within my gear

> "I ain't the sharpest tool in the shed"

anyone who shines is worth a lot

> "And all that glitters is gold"

and it unfortunately never stops.

> "Well, the years start coming and they don't stop coming"

Comment: Well done! Im not english native so I got the rear word wrong it was the opposite.

Comment: @charles-l Can you explain "I am like grass and mountains"?